# Flex - Copying a Single frame from a Video

Tags: apache-flex, video, copy, png, frame

I'm working with video in Flex. I'd like to be able to pause the video at a certain point and copy the displayed frame as an image, and save it to a database. I'm wondering if anybody knows how I might copy a single frame from a paused video?
Thanks
--Matt

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your video is called 'clip'

```
var frameGrab:BitmapData = new BitmapData( clip.width, clip.height, false, 0x000000);
frameGrab.draw(clip); // < the .draw() method will copy the frame from your video.

// Add to the stage...
var frame:Bitmap = new Bitmap(frameGrab);
addChild(frame);
```