# Get random (or first) frame from video using flex

Tags: video, actionscript, flex4, thumbnails

I am developing an application for recording videos and previewing them as tilelist.  Is there any way to capture a frame of the video to use as a thumbnail in my list? I'm using Flex 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i was searching for was the following:

```
        private function capture(filename:String):void
        {   
            var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(videoDisplay.width, videoDisplay.height);            
            bitmapData.draw(videoDisplay,new Matrix());

            var bitmap : Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
            var jpg:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();
            var ba:ByteArray = jpg.encode(bitmapData);
            var newImage:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("foldername/"+filename+".jpg");

            fileStream = new FileStream();
            fileStream.open(newImage, FileMode.UPDATE);
            fileStream.writeBytes(ba);
            fileStream.close();


        }
```

which is a method called when the user clicks to record..so i grab a photo as a thumb! i hope the above will help others too who look for something similar...
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010420/85950):

```
var frameGrab:BitmapData = new BitmapData(clip.width, clip.height, false, 0);
frameGrab.draw(clip); // the .draw() method will copy the frame from your video.
var frame:Bitmap = new Bitmap(frameGrab);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do it:
attach an event listener to the video stream (i.e. `NetStream`), like so:

```
var vConnection:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
vConnection.connect(null);
var vStream:NetStream = new NetStream(vConnection);
vStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatusChange);
```

The listener then looks like this:

```
protected function onNetStatusChange(event:NetStatusEvent):void
{
    switch(event.info.code)
    {
        case "NetStream.Play.Start": 
        {
            vStream.seek(1); // seek to key frame
            break;
        }
        case "NetStream.Video.DimensionChange":
        {
            // after a dimension change we have a loaded frame
            // do whatever you want here, but keep in mind 
            // that the video needs to be on the display list 
            // if you want to draw it   
            break;
        }
        default: break;
    }
}
```